# Must the distance between the reflectors of a coherent laser be a multitude of its intended wavelength?

Tags: optics, reflection, laser, wavelength, coherence

Must the distance (aka cavity length $L$) between the two reflective mirrors of a spatial and temporal coherent laser be a multitude of the lasers intended wavelength?

If no, why not?

If yes, how does changing the cavity length $L$ of the mirrors affect the temporal coherence (or phase)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing between the mirrors that form a laser's resonant cavity determine the set of wavelengths that the laser can amplify and emit.  The spacing constrains the wavelengths $λ$ to those that are an integer fraction of the cavity length $L$:

$λ = \frac{2L}{q}$, with mode order $q \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

The range of emitted wavelengths is also constrained by the lasing medium within the cavity: often a lasing medium can emit only a narrow range of wavelengths.  So what the laser actually emits is a handful of discrete wavelengths simultaneously.

To design a laser to emit a single particular wavelength, it's necessary to choose a lasing medium whose emission spectrum includes the design wavelength, then select a cavity design that allows only the design wavelength to meet resonance conditions.

By moving a mirror to adjust cavity length, the emission wavelength can be shifted.  Typically this has little or no effect on coherence.

Comment: In order for me to accept your answer, would you please add this formula: *"The spacing $d$ constrains the wavelengths to those that are an integer fraction of the cavity length:* $d = n * λ$ *, with* $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ *"* (If you'd like I could add the formula by myself, just let me know...)

Comment: Sure, please add it yourself, but make it lambda = d/n.

Comment: For some reasons it turned out to be half the wavelength: $λ = 2d/n$ (or $2L/q$) according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_mode, I've already corrected it ;-)

Comment: The reason is that the *total* path from one mirror to the other and back to the original mirror must be an integral number of wavelengths.

Comment: True. First I thought this was counter-intuitive, but then I came to realize that this "$λ/2$-rule" applies to any resonance body, e.g. for water in a tank or a swinging guitar string (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28music%29)